# Gradle did not find Minecraft Mappings for 1.12.2?

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I would like to learn minecraft mod development, but there is an error with downloading the mappings

The error message is:

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':runtimeClasspathCopy'.
>
> > Could not find net.minecraftforge:forge:1.12.2-14.23.5.2860_mapped_snapshot_20180814-1.12.
> > Searched in the following locations:
> > - file:~/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/bundeled_repo/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.12.2-14.23.5.2860_mapped_snapshot_20180814-1.12/forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860_mapped_snapshot_20180814-1.12.pom
> > - file:~/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/bundeled_repo/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.12.2-14.23.5.2860_mapped_snapshot_20180814-1.12/forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860_mapped_snapshot_20180814-1.12.jar
> > Required by:
> > project :
>
> Possible solution:
>
> - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

The directories specified does not exist. Also I tried downloading and importing the MCP instead of using an IntelliJ Plugin for Minecraft. The same error occurred while using this but there was a few more links (that leads to a webpage) that does not exists ("error 404 not found") if I clicked them.

The line in build.gradle which specifies the mappings used is at the moment:

```
mappings channel: 'snapshot', version: '20180814-1.12'
```

It was a stable version before and there was the same errors.

Does anyone know what I can do about it?

Comment: what are you using to edit your code, op?
if you aren't already use intellij, that might solve your problem.
another thing you could do is, try setupDecompworkspace, that could solve your problem.

Comment: There is not a setupDecompWorkspace and I am using IntelliJ IDEA

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and i fix it by changing it to java 1.8 eclipse temurin
btw sorry for my bad english